# Set fixed device names for USB ports

Tags: usb

I have four identical cameras connected to the USB ports of my Raspberry 4. I need to make sure that each camera always gets the same device name, because in my script I must be able to say "take a photo with camera 1".

Some articles, for example [this](https://g0kao.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/usb-port-assignment-on-a-raspberry-pi/) suggest to locate the devices using properties like `idVendor`, but this does not seem to work if all the cameras are identical.

So, can I say to my Raspberry Pi: "**Please assign this device name to whatever is connected to the upper left USB port**, that device name to whatever is connected to the upper right USB port and so on"?

Comment: Devices should have a usb serial number you can use to distinguish them, but not always.  Sometimes devices that don't have a unique serial number have a way for you to assign a serial number in the device's firmware. I believe you can tag devices by USB port number as you suggested, it's one of the properties udev recognizes.

Comment: yes you can, for Win and Rpi, but you only assign a com port number, not a com port name.

Comment: What is the problem with using the name under `/sys/devices/`?

Comment: Good question! Have you read this [wiki at Debian's website?](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/USB)

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption:** Raspberry Pi OS (previously called Raspbian) is running on your Raspberry Pi 4, and you are using your USB cameras as video4linux devices.

I do not think that it is possible to give a fixed dev path (such as /dev/videoX) to a USB port on Linux, OR I do not know how to do it (yet!) :(

However, there is a way to know what dev path(s) is/are given for the device plugged in a specific USB port. It is even easier to know them for video4linux devices. When having the mapping, I think it should be very straightforward to achieve what you need in your script.

(I use optional plural noun "dev path(s)", because a physical device can provide more than one interfaces which can result in multiple dev paths)

You know what they say... "*Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.*" I want to follow the latter one ;)

It is good to have an understanding of USB host controllers, hubs, devices, ports and etc. There is a resource which can be a good starting point for those who are interested in, you can give it a read: [Interpreting the output of lsusb](https://diego.assencio.com/?index=1363692dafeabeff8e3f975077f92dfe)

Let us try to understand "USB things" of Raspberry Pi. (I use Raspberry Pi 3 since I do not have Raspberry Pi 4)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=smsc95xx, 480M
```

When nothing is plugged in USB ports, we have the above output where we see;

- in the first line, there is a single USB host controller (Bus 01) on which a root_hub (Dev 1) is directly attached.
- in the second line, there is a hub (Dev 2) which is connected to Port 1 of the USB host controller/root_hub (Dev 1).
- in the third line, there is a device (Dev 3) which is connected to Port 1 of the hub (Dev 2).

Dev 2 is the hub which provides the external USB ports you see on Raspberry Pi board.

But wait! There was no USB device plugged in to USB ports, why do we see Dev 3 connected to Port 1 of the hub (Dev 2)? Do not panic! It is the ethernet adapter which is a built-in/already installed USB device on the board.

Let us focus on the 4 external USB ports of the board. We can find their naming (such as Port 2,3,4,5) by simply plugging in a USB device (such as a mouse or a camera) to each port.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=smsc95xx, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

When I plug my camera in to the upper left USB port, I see the above output. So, we can say that the upper left USB port is named "Port 2", and the plugged device is named "Dev 4".

For the Raspberry Pi 3 I have, the mapping is as follow, it can be different on other boards. You need to figure out the mapping.

- Port 2: the upper left USB port
- Port 3: the lower left USB port
- Port 4: the upper right USB port
- Port 5: the lower right USB port

Also, did you notice that there are two interfaces (If 0 and 1) provided by Dev 4? I am not sure, but I think it is for providing different device capabilities via interfaces.

Let us take it one step further by plugging in another USB camera which is more sophisticated than the one already plugged in.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=smsc95xx, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

As you can see in the above output, the sophisticated camera has a built-in hub (Dev 5), and two devices (Dev 6 and 7) are connected on Port 3 and 4 of this hub. Dev 6 is a video device with two interfaces (If 0 and 1) provided.

As a summary, so far we have;

- "Dev 4: video device" connected to "Port 2" of "Dev 2: hub" connected to "Port 1" of "Dev 1: USB host controller/root hub"
- "Dev 6: video device" connected to "Port 3" of "Dev 5: hub" connected to "Port 5" of "Dev 2: hub" connected to "Port 1" of "Dev 1: USB host controller/root hub"

or in short, we have;

- a video device at usb-1.2
- another video device at usb-1.5.3

The second digits from left are numbers of the external USB ports.

OK, I think we can say that we now have an understanding of "USB things" at some level, so let us list [USB port, dev path(s)] mappings for video4linux devices with a single line command :) You can parse its output to create a mappings list in your script.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV (usb-3f980000.usb-1.2):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1

USB Camera: USB Camera (usb-3f980000.usb-1.5.3):
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
```

There are two video4linux devices connected to the external USB ports 2 and 5. Each device has two interfaces/two dev paths. It is up to you which interface to use for each video device.

You can see the device capabilities of each interface with the this command:
`v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/videoX --all`. Replace '/dev/videoX' with the dev path you want to get details.

Answer (score 0):

Stick with the `udev` approach linked in your question, but include the serial number field to disambiguate identical devices with the same vendor and model. Each device will typically have a unique serial number so the `udev` approach can be made as specific as needed.

Check out the `ATTRS{serial}` field example shown [here](https://inegm.medium.com/persistent-names-for-usb-serial-devices-in-linux-dev-ttyusbx-dev-custom-name-fd49b5db9af1). That'll provide unique `/dev/myTTY` mappings for each unique serial number.